# What is the point of naming Tony Stark's dream son after his comic book rival?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, reference, avengers-infinity-war, comic-adaptation

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Tony had this conversation with Pepper:

> **Tony Stark:** Right! That's the point I'm trying to make. Last night, I dreamt, we had a kid. So real. We named him after your eccentric uncle. Uh, what was his name?
>
> **Pepper Potts:** Right.
>
> **Tony Stark:** Morgan! Morgan. <sub>[source](http://transcripts.wikia.com/wiki/Avengers:_Infinity_War)</sub>

I though it must be some comic book character name and I can only find [Morgan Stark](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Morgan_Stark_(Earth-616)), who is a cousin of Tony that hates him and tries to harm him many times.

So what is the point of naming Tony's dream son based on his enemy from comics? Or is it based on some other Morgan?

Comment: "Morgan Freeman Stark",  may be this ...

Comment: "*Tony Stark*: We named him after *your* eccentric uncle." shouldn't that be Peppers uncle? And not Tonys?

Comment: @jnovacho nobody said Tony had uncle with that name but he will get his surname and will be called  Morgan Stark not  Morgan Potts

Comment: @AnkitSharma It seems unlikely that either Tony's son or Pepper's uncle would also be Tony's cousin. There might still be some relevance, but I doubt either of them is actually supposed to be the "Morgan Stark" from the comics.

Comment: @KamilDrakari Is everybody talking past each other here? :-) In his dream, Tony and Pepper named their son after Pepper's uncle Morgan [Potts or whatevs]. Their son's full name would then probably be *Morgan Stark*. And that is the same name as that of Tony's cousin *in the Comics Universe*. As far as we know, the *cousin* Morgan Stark doesn't exist in the Cinematic Universe.

Comment: @Zano I think I figured out what's happening now. OP was *not* asking the question "Is Pepper's uncle supposed to be the character 'Morgan Stark' from the comics" as jnovacho and I assumed, but instead the question is "Is the (hypothetical) son named 'Morgan Stark' in MCU a reference to the character 'Morgan Stark' in the comics? If so, why?"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is one of those Easter eggs Marvel put in their movies. Morgan Stark happens to be Tony's cousin and enemy in comics, but they named his future son. It seems that Marvel wants to try something new other than comics and release new movies with new characters in MCU (though no confirmation yet). This might be explained in future (possibly with release of Infinity War sequel)

In [one interview](https://www.thewrap.com/avengers-infinity-war-gwenyth-paltrow-just-revealed-tony-stark-is-going-to-be-a-father/) with Gwyneth Paltrow (who plays Pepper Potts), she told about the future relationship of her character with Tony Stark. (might be a **spoiler** for upcoming movie. **Ye be warned**)

> “Pepper and Tony have had a really long journey together,” Paltrow said in the interview. “She obviously starts as his dutiful assistant, and then the relationship evolves, and now this decade later they’re married, and they have a child. Their relationship has evolved in all of the ways that great romances evolve.”

Though, Pepper Potts denies the dream of Tony about having a child and naming him Morgan, but this statement suggests that there might be something to his dream after all. Morgan Stark will possibly be his son in MCU and then made one or more movies about him.

From the same article (with my edits and emphasis),

> If there’s a baby on the way **that could confirm some potential theories about where the MCU is headed in the future.** At the very least, **it would provide Tony a good reason to retire from superheroing, which seems likely since Downey’s MCU contract ends with “Avengers 4” in 2019.** If he hangs up the Iron Man suit to become a family man, that would allow Marvel to keep Tony around for occasional cameos and assistance in the MCU — and that feels more likely than killing the character off.

Answer (score 13):

This would appear to be simply an Easter egg, for those watching the film who are familiar with Morgan Stark from the comics. Marvel have been throwing in Easter eggs like that ever since *Iron Man 1*, where the military jets that pursue Stark are codenamed "Whiplash 1" and "Whiplash 2", and the terrorist organisation that captures Tony is named "the Ten Rings". At that time, there were no plans for *Iron Man 2* or *3* (or indeed, the MCU as a whole), so those were mere Easter eggs rather than foreshadowing of those characters' later appearances.